# "Trying to get properties on a non-object" in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm a WordPress theme developer and on a theme I'm working on, I've turned on debug mode and get this error inside a select drop-down box for the theme's options page.

The error says this: "Trying to get properties on a non-object." Here is the offending code:

```
 <select name="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" id="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>">
                <?php foreach ($value['options'] as $option) { ?>
               <option value="<?php echo $option->term_id; ?>"  <?php if ( $settings[$id] == $option->term_id) { echo 'selected="selected"'; }?>>
                    <?php echo $option->name; ?>
                </option>                       
               <?php }?>  </select>
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. The line that's specifically causing the error is this:

```
<option value="<?php echo $option->term_id; ?>"  <?php if ( $settings[$id] == $option->term_id) { echo 'selected="selected"'; }?>>
```

Thanks for any advice! :)

Comment: Oh, and I'm not interested in suppressing these notices in PHP.ini. I actually do need to fix the error!

Comment: Well, what is `$option`? Try `var_dump($option)`.

Comment: are you sure the `$value['options']` is populated?

Comment: $option was defined in the foreach loop...

Comment: But what *is it*? It's obviously not an object, even though you're treating it like one.

Comment: I'll check it, though. Also, the code actually does work properly when Debug is turned off. I'm just not sure how to get it to stop showing those notices. $option is supposed to be the values in a <select> list, from which users can pick a category to display.

Comment: Simply do `var_dump($option)` to see what `$option` actually *is*, which will tell you how to handle it.

Comment: OK when I do that I get bool(false)

Comment: But it is definitely an array, so I'm confused, lol

Comment: If it's `false` it's definitely *not* an array. You'll need to trace that value back to see where it came from and why it's not what you expect.

Comment: Ok, if I do a var_dump on $value['options'], I get all of my array values. But if I do a var_dump on $option, I just get bool(false). That's strange...  And how do I do a trace? Sorry, I'm still new to PHP!

Comment: update your question with `var_export($value['options']);`

Comment: When I do that var_export, I get a huge array with the following (this is just the first index in the array): array ( 0 => stdClass::__set_state(array( 'term_id' => '3', 'name' => 'aciform', 'slug' => 'aciform', 'term_group' => '0', 'term_taxonomy_id' => '3', 'taxonomy' => 'category', 'description' => '', 'parent' => '0', 'count' => '2', 'cat_ID' => '3', 'category_count' => '2', 'category_description' => '', 'cat_name' => 'aciform', 'category_nicename' => 'aciform', 'category_parent' => '0', )),

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're doing this a couple of times:

```
$option->someproperty
```

In at least one of the cases `$option` is not an object.  When you then do `->` on a non-object, you get that error.

First, verify that `$option` is actually an object and correct the usage if it is not.

If `$option` is an array then @matthewpavkov is correct, you should do `$option['someproperty']` instead of `$option->someproperty`.

If `$option` is usually an object, perhaps `get_categories()` is sometimes returning `null` or `false` in a failure condition.  Check for that before accessing `$option`.

Like so:

```
foreach ($value['options'] as $option)
{
    if ($option)
    {
        // do whatever;
    }
}
```

Comment: OMG Evan, this worked! Wow, I've been at this problem for nearly two days and this simple statement fixed it. Thank you so much, and thanks to everyone else who answered, I really appreciate all of your help!!

Comment: You're quite welcome!  PHP is full of quirky things like this.  Keep that in mind for the future!

Comment: Yes, definitely! I've learned more about PHP over the past few days than I have in this entire year, lol.

Comment: @ajreal - is_object() while "safer" is overkill.  Typically a function returns what you expect it to (in this case an object) or null/false for failure.  The if($object) catches that majority case.  If the function returns any one of several different, but valid, types then typically the function has a flawed design or you need to do a lot more logic processing the results - because they're all valid.  But, I can't think of any function that validly would return any of an array or an object or a float.  Can you?

Comment: wrong answer, if the $option is anything not null and not an object, your code will fail, **PS: is_object is never overkill**

Comment: @ajreal - you need to go back and read my full answer.  It depends on what $option is.  From my answer: "First, verify that $option is actually an object and correct the usage if it is not." The "Like so:" code above is ONLY for use when "If $option is usually an object, perhaps get_categories() is sometimes returning null or false in a failure condition."  In that case it is only ever an object OR null/false.  No other checking is required. ALSO: is_object takes one third MORE TIME than "if" so is inefficient and therefore overkill if you know you are never going to get, say, an integer back.

Comment: wrong answer again, there is `gettype`, and again `is_object` is overkill

Comment: I agree, is_object is overkill :-D - also `gettype` is about 5x worse than a simple `if` check.  Both are way less efficient, so overkill when you know what the results are going to be.  You should know what the results are going to be because you're the coder and you should be able to accurately predict what the function will return.  Don't put hate in the world.  Give credit where credit is due.  My answer accurately fixed the problem at hand.  And I didn't need the results of a `var_dump()` or `var_export()` to do it. Just some php programming experience.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that `$option` is an array. Try:

```
$option['term_id']
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but I got a fatal error. Did you mean putting this in place of $option->term_id?

Answer (score 0):

OK I see what you're saying. Earlier in my code I have this (overly simplified, just to show the important parts):

```
$news_categories = get_categories()  //pulls all of the categories from WordPress

        array ("minititle"      => '<span class="mini_title">Select the category you\'d like to use as your "Top Story" category.</span>',
            "id"        => $shortname . "_top_story_category",
            "type"      => "cat_select",
            "options" => $news_categories)
```

This is where $value['options'] comes from. The code is part of a switch statement...

I would have to post the entire file in order to give the context, and it's quite long.

Comment: You should edit the question and add this information to it rather than making it an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Execute it from action...i.e.:

```
function your_function(){
    YOUR CODES HEREEEEEEEEEEE............
}
ADD_ACTION('init','your_function');
```